# How can I specify the order of curried parameter application

Tags: functional-programming, composition, currying, ramda.js

I'm trying to convert the following to pointfree style: a function that partially applies a value to the transformer function `add` before passing in the collection to be iterated over. (Using Ramda.js)

```
R.compose(
  R.map,
  R.add
)(1, [1,2,3])
```

The problem is that `R.add` is arity 2, as is `R.map`. I want the application order to be as follows:

```
add(1)
map(add(1))
map(add(1), [1,2,3])
[add(1,1), add(1,2), add(1,3)]
```

But what happens instead is this:

```
add(1, [1,2,3])
map(add(1, [1,2,3]))
<partially applied map, waiting for collection>
```

Anyone know of a way to specify this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain `compose` or `pipe` won't do this because either will absorb all the arguments supplied into the first function.  Ramda includes two additional functions that help with this, [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) and [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith).  In this case `useWith` is the one that will help:

```
useWith(map, [add, identity])(1, [1, 2, 3]); //=> [2, 3, 4]
```

While `identity` is not absolutely required here, it gives the generated function the correct arity.

Comment: That's so much more elegant. Thanks (and I'm big fan of your work)!

Comment: Perhaps it is more elegant, but I'd never thought about your `nAry` / `uncurry` technique before.  That might be more challenging for this specific case, but it is also more flexible and more general.  Interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. If anyone's curious, here's the gist. (You can try it in the console on [RamdaJS.com](http://ramdajs.com/).)

0) For a baseline, here's the pointed version.

```
func0 = x => R.map(R.add(x))
addOne = func0(1)
addOne([1,2,3]) // [2,3,4]
```

1) Here's the pointfree core, but it has the ordering problem from the question above.

```
func1 = R.compose(R.map, R.add)
addOne = func1(1)
addOne([1,2,3]) // [2,3,4])
func1(1, [1,2,3]) // function
```

2) If the composition is `unary` (arity 1) 2 invocations are needed apply all params.

```
func2 = R.unary(R.compose(R.map, R.add))
addOne = func2(1)
addOne([1,2,3]) // [2,3,4])
```

3) We want one invocation to apply both params, so we `uncurry` 2.

```
func3 = R.uncurryN(2, func2)
func3(1, [1,2,3]) // [2,3,4])
```

4) To prove func2 is composable, let's double the results.

```
func4 = R.compose(
  R.map(R.multiply(2)), 
  R.uncurryN(2, func2)
)
func4(1, [1,2,3]) // [4,6,8])
```

5) Substitution gives us a completely pointfree function.

```
func5 = R.compose(
  R.map(R.multiply(2)),
  R.uncurryN(2, R.unary(R.compose(
    R.map,
    R.add
  )))
)
func5(1, [1,2,3]) // [4,6,8])
```